# Change in class type for output of numba guvectorize with numpy update

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numba

I am in the process of updating numpy from 1.15.2 -> 1.16.6 for a project. In this project we have a subclass of numpy.ndarray which implements `__array_wrap__` and `__array_finalize__`. Additionally, there are functions which are made into gufuncs through the use of numba's guvectorize decorator.

The case I am seeing an issue with is calling the guvectorized gufunc with instances of the ndarray subclasses.

With numpy 1.15.2 stepping through the code I see that `def __array_wrap__(self, obj, context=None)` is called with obj as an instance of the ndarray subclass.

However, once numpy is upgraded to 1.16.6 `def __array_wrap__(self, obj, context=None)` is called with obj as an instance of ndarray. Which causes some issues with the logic in the `__array_wrap__` code.

I was hoping for clarification on:

1. Why this behavior change is occurring? (I can't find any references to this in the numpy release notes)
2. If it is possible to replicate the old behavior for the output of a gufunc created by numba guvectorize to retain the class of the input (with the highest `__array_priority__`)? Or will the output always be of class ndarray?